# button.getText() в Java

Tags: java

Добрый день, вот простенькая программа. Пытаюсь получить в переменную новую надпись на кнопке, ничего не получается:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class Button {
    static JButton button1 = new JButton();
}



class ButtonListener1 extends Button implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button1.setText("Привет");
        Font BigFontTR = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 100);
        button1.setFont(BigFontTR);
    }

}

public class Jitik extends ButtonListener1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Jitik");
        frame.setSize(800, 1000);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener1());
        frame.setVisible(true);

        String s = button1.getText();
        System.out.println(s);


    }
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста, как мне получить в переменную s новую надпись на кнопке?

Comment: А что именно не получается? Опишите подробнее

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы в переменную s записалось слово "Привет"

Comment: Продолжаем допрос... А что получается вместо этого?

Comment: Ничего не выводится. Мне нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку в переменную s записалось "Привет". И дальше я мог уже с этой переменной делать нужные мне манипуляции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так ведь это тоже должно быть в actionPerformed, после setText, потому что listener'ы асинхронные.
И у вас не ничего не получается, а у кнопки пустой текст и он и выводится в консоль, если вы сделаете так System.out.println("|" + s + "|"); то все станет ясно, а пока вы просто тупите в силу недостаточно развитого нужного типа мышления.